# mercurial temporarily ignore versioned files

Tags: mercurial, ignore

My question is essentially the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839058/ignore-all-changes-to-a-versioned-folder-in-svn-without-deleting-from-repo) but applies to mercurial. I have a set of files that are under version control, and one save operation changes quite a lot of files. Some of the resulting changes are important for revision control, and some of the changes are just junk. I can "partition" off the junk into separate files. These junk files need to be part of a basic checkout in order for it to work, but their contents (and changes over time) aren't that important for revision control. Right now I just tell all our developers not to commit these files, but we all forget and it creates a lot of extra baggage in the repository. I don't really like the svn solution proposed because there are quite a lot of files and I want a simple clone to just work without all this extra manual work, so I was wondering if mercurial has a better alternative. It's kind of like hg shelve but not quite, and kind of like ignore, but not quite. Is there some hg extension that allows for this? Can git do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! So TortoiseHG's repository and global settings have an Auto Exclude List where you can define a list of files that will be unchecked by default when the status, commit, and shelve dialogs open. So they still show up, but the user has to check them in order to actually do a commit. The setting is stored in hgrc, but it's under the [tortoisehg] heading so it's not supported by mercurial per se. Nevertheless, it fits my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Mercurial doesn't support this.  The correct way to do it is to commit `thefile.sample` and then have your developers (or better you deploy script) do a copy from `thefile.sample` to `thefile` if `thefile` doesn't exist.  That way anyone can update the example file, but there's no risk of them committing their local changes (say their personal database connect string).

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this is to use nested tree support (submodule in git), where the "junk" would be put in a different repository (to avoid cluttering the main repo), while enabling checking out the whole thing out in a consistent manner (right version of both repos in sync).

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos

In git, submodules are one solution to this issue - but they are not that great UI-wise. What I do instead is to keep two completely independent repositories, and using the subtree merge strategy when I need to update the main repo with the junk repo: http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I don't think I'm going to use it in this case, but the sub-repo option is definitely good to know for future projects.

Comment: yes, I would be the first to admit it is kind of heavyweight for your usecase.